# Асимптотическая сложность операции обхода для вложенных map

Tags: java, алгоритм, java-8, time-complexity

Пусть у меня есть такая структура данных :

```
NavigableMap<Long, NavigableMap<Long, Set<String> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Я хочу подсчитать асимптотическую сложность для алгоритма ниже:

```
SortedSet<Widget> result = new TreeSet<>();

map.tailMap(first, true)
        .forEach( (k, v)-> {
            v.headMap(second, true)
                    .forEach((key, value) -> result.addAll(value));
        });
```

Прав ли я , если считаю что сложность будет

```
O(log (n + k) * (log (k + m) + log (m))) ?
```

Где

- *n* - количество элементов в оригинальной *map*,
- *k* - количество элементов в *tailMap(first, true)*,
- *m* - количество элементов в *headMap(second, true)*

Answer (score 1):

Пусть n - число ключей в `map`, n' - индекс ключа `first` в `map`.

Пусть m<sub>i</sub> - число ключей в `map[i]`, где i последовательный номер ключа `map` в диапазоне [0, n). Соответственно m'<sub>i</sub> - номер ключа `second` в `map[i]`.

Пусть k<sub>i,j</sub> - суммарное число символов в строках множества `map[i][j]`.

Тогда сложность алгоритма будет log n + (n - n') + ∑<sub>n'≤i<n</sub> m'<sub>i</sub> + ∑<sub>n'≤i<n</sub> ∑<sub>j<m'<sub>i</sub></sub> k<sub>i,j</sub>.

log n - поиск ключа `first` в `map`;

(n - n') - итерация от `first` до конца `map`;

∑m'<sub>i</sub> - `headMap` не требует поиска первого ключа, итерация происходит пока очередной ключ не станет больше `second`.

∑∑k<sub>i,j</sub> - сложность вычисления хеш-функции от всех строк и добавление строк в результат. Предполагается, что хеш-функция хорошая и конфликтов мало.

Простыми словами: сложность пропорциональна количеству байт, которые будут просмотрены при переборе карт (и ещё один логарифм). В худшем случае сложность пропорциональна памяти, отведённой под карты и строки.

Если бы не логарифм, я бы сказал сложность линейная. Логарифм может проявиться если `headMap` будет перебирать совсем мало элементов `map`.